# I can't delete a Postgresql database because it always has active sessions no matter what

Tags: postgresql

I want to delete a Postgresq database. At 1st attempt I get:

```
There are 15 other sessions using the database.
```

I do this:

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE db1 FROM public; 


SELECT pid, pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE datname = current_database() AND pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

But this doesn't help - I still can't delete the db because there're still active sessions.

I restart postgresql service and to no avail - after 1 second there're 15 sessions automatically.

Why? How to delete the db?

Comment: You clearly have some applications attempting to connect to the database--it would be safest to stop those applications and then attempt to drop the database

Comment: @richyen that app has been stopped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = 'false' WHERE datname = 'databasename';
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'databasename';
drop database databasename;
```

Answer (score 2):

I sounds like you have a connection pooler which is re-establishing connections just as fast as possible.  And it is allowed to, either because it is connecting as a superuser, or through a user or role which has been granted CONNECT by name (rather than just through PUBLIC).

You could revoke CONNECT from any other users and roles, and try again with the `pg_terminate_backend`.  Or you could add a `reject` line to the top of pg_hba.conf for that database.  But maybe the simplest is just to drop the database really fast after the restart, by putting the drop command on the same terminal line as the restart command.

```
pg_ctl restart ; psql -c 'drop database db1'
```

Comment: `You could revoke CONNECT from any other users and roles` -- that's what I've done, I've mentioned this in my question

Comment: what to do stop a pool of connections?

Comment: @Totto You only mentioned revoking from PUBLIC.  That is not the same thing.